# Редактирование выборки

Tags: delphi, interbase, sql

Возможно ли редактирование данных выборки, полученных в DBGrid в результате SQL-запроса?
Если да, то какими средствами это можно организовать?
Запрос выполняю через IBQuery. 
То есть, я выполняю запрос на вывод данных по какому-либо условию. Затем, результат запроса возвращает данные в связанную с IBQuery таблицу DBGrid. Но при этом я понимаю, что это всего лишь результат запроса, который нельзя редактировать. А мне бы хотелось добавить такой функционал, как редактирование выбранных по какому-либо условию данных.

Comment: Возможно все, если сформулируете вопрос нормально то вам помогут.

Comment: А вы скажете, что именно не понимаете, я с превеликим удовольствием объясню!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBGrid не получает никаких данных, и в нем вы ничего не отредактируете. DBGrid только отображает выборку. Все редактирование происходит только запросами.

Comment: Ну на самом деле в самом гриде то отредактировать возможно) возникает впорос как записать результаты труда в базу...
Т.с.'у стоит взглянуть на визуальные компоненты для редактирования, насколько помню таковые были в стандартной поставке, а лучше отказаться от идеи юзать дбгрид, и пересесть на СтрингГрид\ДравГрид.

Comment: @ToRcH565, а вы, месьё, знаете толк в извращениях. По мне так уже проще SQL подучить, и делать нормальную выборку:) И опять же, сделать гибкую настройку отбора, посредством конструктора SQL запросов (который предлагаю автору сабжа написать). И когда пользователь получит нужный ему результат, тогда предлагать гибкую систему редактирования, опять же внутри это будут запросы.  
А все эти танцы с бубнами.. ну да, можно сделать для галочки :)

Answer (score 2):

Редактировать результат запроса можно в некоторых случаях. Какие запросы редактируются а какие нет, не уточняется, но всегда есть возможность использования TIBUpdateSQL.

Т.е. создаем TIBUpdateSQL, для TIBQuery указываем его в свойстве UpdateObject.
У IBUpdateSQL есть четыре свойства:

- DeleteSQL. Запрос будет вида

  ```
   delete from MyTable
   where
     id = :OLD_id
  ```

  `:OLD_id` - спец параметр, который будет автоматом передаваться при редактировании текущей записи. Т.е. заполнять его не нужно, ключевым является префикс OLD_.
- InsertSQL. Запрос будет вида:

  ```
   insert into MyTable
   (field1, field2, field3)
   values (:field1, :field2, :field3)
  ```

  `:field1`, `:field2`, `:field3` - параметры, содержащие значения соответствующих полей. Также значения подставятся автоматом для полей с соответствующими именами.
- ModifySQL. Запрос вида:

  ```
   update MyTable
   set field1 = :field1
   where id = :OLD_id
  ```
- RefreshSQL. Тот же запрос, который используется в TIBQuery.

Заполнять или нет соответствующие запросы - зависит от логики программы. Если какой-то из запросов будет не заполнен, соответственно и добавление/удаление/редактирование будет не доступно.