# Сохранение в Blob-поля в FireBird

Tags: delphi, firebird, sql

Имеется таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE HOOKNAMES (
HN_ID             SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
HN_NAME           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
HN_LEVEL          SMALLINT NOT NULL,
HN_IMAGE          BLOB);
```

Первые 3 поля заполняю так:

```
Form1.IBSql1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.IBSql1.SQL.Append('INSERT INTO HOOKNAMES (HN_ID, HN_NAME, HN_LEVEL) ');
Form1.IBSql1.SQL.Append('VALUES ('+TempBuf[3]+', '+TempBuf[0]+', '+TempBuf[1]+')');
Form1.IBSql1.ExecQuery;
```

Последнее поле пробую добавить следующим образом (пример нашёл на этом сайте):

```
Form1.HookNamesDS.Edit;
TBlobField(Form1.HookNamesDS.FieldByName('HN_IMAGE')).LoadFromFile('..\bilder\image.png');
Form1.HookNamesDS.Post;
```

`Var HookNamesDS: TIBDataSet;`

Получаю ошибку при попытке изменить DataSet, который только для чтения, в нём не задан DataSource, просто выбрана вся таблица через SelectSQL. 
Каким образом в данном примере идёт привязка именно к нужной строке?
Каким образом нужно правильно инициализировать DataSet? И как правильно с ним работать?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вот оно! :) Я думал DataSet прикручивают только потому, что иначе в BLOB поле не вписать ничего, а всё гениальное, как обычно, просто) IBSql тоже это умеет.

Да, мне просто создание и заполнение БД нужно было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам сначала надо добиться, чтоб таблица была модифицируемая. Если вы используете `TIBDataSet`, то необходимо прописать все sql запросы: `SelectSQL`, `ModifySQL`, `DeleteSQL`, `InsertSQL`. Если вы добавите компонент на форму, можно задать эти запросы в визуальном редакторе (пкм на компоненте, Dataset editor...), выбираете в нем имя таблицы, запросы создадутся, afair сами. Если вы создаете компонент в рантайме, значит надо прописать эти же запросы в коде. Про тексты запросов писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/172552/delphi-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8).

После того как вы получите модифицируемый dataset, уже можно приступать к сохранению blob'ов.

**UPD** По поводу TIBSQL. Никогда не пишите запросы так. Всегда пользуйтесь параметрами.

**UPD2** Если вы добавляете или редактируете несуществующую запись (например, таблица пустая - будет вызван Insert), в этом случае вам надо заполнить и `HN_ID`. Для изменения, как в вопросе, `HookNamesDS.Edit` - `HN_ID` у вас для текущей записи должно быть уже заполнено. В любом случае заполнять надо поле, а не параметр. Параметры будут заполняться сами, этим занимается компонент.

```
with Form1.HookNamesDS do
begin
  Insert;
  FieldByName('HN_ID').AsString:=TempBuf[3];
  // остальные поля
  TBlobField(FieldByName('HN_IMAGE')).LoadFromFile('..\bilder\image.png');
  Post;
end;
```

А так, должен работать ваш код из вопроса.

Comment: Cпасибо, запросы прописались, ошибка пропала.

SQL запросы прописались в принципе так же, как вы по ссылке выше описывали, лишнее удалил.

А как теперь корректно загрузить картинку в базу и связать с BLOB полем? А как передать параметры?  
При попытке

    TBlobField(Form1.HookNamesDS.FieldByName('HN_IMAGE')).LoadFromFile('..\bilder\image.png');

Ошибка, "параметр HN_ID должен быть задан".   
При попытке

    Form1.HookNamesDS.ParamByName('HN_ID').AsString:=TempBuf[3];

"Поле 'HN_ID' не найдено".

Comment: **обновил ответ**

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает теперь!

Comment: А возможно вместо этого компонента использовать что-то другое в качестве DataSet? Каким-то он кажется надуманным со своими излишними скритами для каждой операции... Или может можно вообще без него обойтись при заполнении BLOB поля? Работало всё без них, а из за одного поля приходится городить

Comment: @Isaev, разумеется. TIBDataset предназначен для любых наборов данных, получаемых из произвольных запросов. Для редактирования одной таблицы достаточно TIBTable.

Comment: У меня парсится одна таблица, в зависимости от определённых параметров разбивается в одном цикле, и из неё создаются параллельно 6 таблиц... При данном подходе приходится или создавать 6 IBDataSet для каждой будущей таблицы, или создавать 1 и перед каждой записью закрывать его, менять ему запрос Insert, открывать заново... Как-то это неправильно. При IBTable всё равно будет 6 компонентов же.

Comment: Так же, как и с одним IBDataSet, так же можно и с IBTable, меняя у нее свойство TableName. 

    with ibTab do 
    begin
      Close; 
      TableName:='tab2';
      Open;
      // какие-то действия
    end;

Comment: @Isaev, да, если вам надо выполнить просто запросы по вставке, то вы можете использовать TIBSQL (с этим компонентом используем параметры):

    with Form1.IBSql1 do begin
      SQL.Text:= 'INSERT INTO HOOKNAMES (HN_ID, HN_IMAGE) '+
        'VALUES (:HN_ID, :HN_IMAGE)';
      ParamByName('HN_ID').AsString:=TempBuf[3];
      ParamByName('HN_IMAGE').LoadFromFile('...');
      ExecQuery;
    end;

В общем, все зависит от ваших потребностей. Вполне естественно, что пользоваться надо тем, что проще и больше подходит для каждого отдельного случая.